# How to use local storage on append child

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<button id="showlinks" onclick="myFunction">show</button>
<div id="buttonlinks"></div>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  document.getElementById("buttonlinks").appendChild(button);
}
```

I used This Code to create buttons on clicking a button. when clicking the show button the buttons appear but after refresh they are gone.

can I store the buttons with localStorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the information about your buttons in the `localStorage` whenever you create a button, and add an eventListener to `window.onload` to read the buttons from `localStorage` and append it to the page when page has loaded, in the below exmpale to keep it simple, I just store the length of buttons.

```
<button id="showlinks" onclick="myFunction">show</button> <div id="buttonlinks"></div>
```

js:

```
 let buttonsLength = 0;

 document.getElementById('showlinks').addEventListener('click', function () {
    createButton();
    buttonsLength++;
    localStorage.setItem('buttonsLength', buttonsLength)
  });

  function createButton() {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerHTML = 'click me';
    document.getElementById('buttonlinks').appendChild(button);
  }

  window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    buttonsLength = Number(localStorage.getItem('buttonsLength')) || 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < buttonsLength; i++) {
      createButton();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const showlinks = document.getElementById('showlinks')

showlinks.addEventListener("click", function () {
  localStorage.setItem("showClicked", true)
  displayButtonInDom()
})

function displayButtonInDom() {
  const showClicked = localStorage.getItem("showClicked")
  if (showClicked) {
  const button = document.createElement("button"); 
  button.innerText = "click me"
  document.getElementById("buttonlinks").appendChild(button);
  }
}
displayButtonInDom()
```

```html
<button id="showlinks">show</button>
<div id="buttonlinks"></div>
```

Comment: but it works for only 1 button

Comment: Can you please write what kind of functionality you are trying to achieve.

Comment: your code worked but only for 1 button for example i need to create 5 buttons how can i do it?

Comment: Do you want to add buttons one by one or all buttons at once?

Comment: i need to add one by one

Answer (score 1):

Foreache button created you have to add the button information to the localstorage. And on page load you execute an init function that rebuild all button created from the localstorage

```
<button id="showlinks" onclick="createButton('')">show</button>
<div id="buttonlinks"></div>


<script>
function Initbutton() {
  //on load check if the button has been already add using the localStorage
  var buttons = getButtonInformationFromLocalStorage(); 
  if(buttons != null){
    buttons.forEach(function(btnName){
      createButton(btnName);
    })
  }
}
// fo the purpose of having different button name 
// i have picket this function here https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/find+random+name+javascript
function getRandomString(length) {
    var randomChars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var result = '';
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        result += randomChars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * randomChars.length));
    }
    return result;
}

function createButton(btnName){
    if(btnName == undefined || btnName == ""){
      btnName = "button" + getRandomString(10);
          updateButtonInformationToLocalStorage(btnName);

    }
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML  = btnName;
    document.getElementById("buttonlinks").appendChild(button); 

    
   
}

function updateButtonInformationToLocalStorage(name){
   var lstrg = localStorage.getItem("alreadyaddbuttontobuttonlinks");
  if(lstrg == null){
    localStorage.setItem("alreadyaddbuttontobuttonlinks", name);
    return name;
  }else{
    var nLstrg = lstrg + "|" + name;
    localStorage.setItem("alreadyaddbuttontobuttonlinks", nLstrg);
    return nLstrg;
  }  
}


function getButtonInformationFromLocalStorage(){
   var lstrg = localStorage.getItem("alreadyaddbuttontobuttonlinks");
  if(lstrg == null){ 
    return null;
  }else{    
    return lstrg.split("|");
  }  
}




window.onload = Initbutton();




</script>
```